# Iterate over n rows of arrays, then next n rows and so on in python

Tags: python

I have C arrays which looks like this

```
array([23, 23, 23, ..., 68, 34, 42])
```

Its indexes are stored in another array D which looks like

```
array([[23989, 10991, 81533, ..., 75050, 13817, 47678],
       [54864, 54830, 89396, ..., 22709, 14556, 62298],
       [ 2936, 28729,  4404, ..., 21431, 81187, 49178],
       ...,
       [30737, 12974, 41031, ..., 43003, 61132, 33385],
       [64713, 53207, 49529, ..., 72596, 76406, 15207],
       [29503, 71648, 27210, ..., 31298, 47102, 13024]])
```

Each row contains around 30 random indexes of C.
What I want to do is use first 10 rows for the 300 randomly drawn indexes of C, and then next 10 rows for the next 300 randomly drawn indexes andof so on.

I can randomly draw 1000 sets of 30 observations from C using the code

```
means_size_30 = C[D].mean(axis=1)
plt.hist(means_size_30)
plt.axvline(np.mean(C))
```

But how do I get 10 rows and then the next ten rows to get the desired result?
Adding for-loop only gets me the mean of individual row (with 30 observations), what I want is the mean of first 10 rows , then the next 10 rows and so on.

```
for i in range(0,1000,10):
    means_size_300 = C[D[i:i+10,:]].mean(axis=1)
    print(C[D[i:i+10,:]])
    print(means_size_300)
plt.hist(means_size_300)
plt.axvline(np.mean(C))
```

Comment: You write a loop in steps of 10.  Where are you stuck?  You know how to index the array; is it with the looping or the slicing?  Both topics are readily available in many tutorials.  Also, you might tell us what `array` package you've used.

Comment: Just a guess, but is the `array` from `numpy`? (with `from numpy import *`)

Comment: I haven't used any array package and the issue is with the  for loop , I can't seem to get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
for row_index in range(0, n, 10):
     array[row_index:row_index+10, :]
```

Comment: Hi, it is working partially, as it is taking the mean of a single row in the 10 group rows, I actually want the mean of all the 10 rows. I have updated my code above. Thanks